# VBA Find function ignores percentages -> only finds decimals

Tags: vba, excel

My macro searches all open workbooks for the active cell value (e.g. 98%). However, it only finds the value 0.98 but not the value 98% in other cells. Why?

Here is my macro:

```
Sub FindIt2()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim wBook As Workbook
Dim rFound As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
lookfor = Selection.Value

On Error Resume Next
For Each wBook In Application.Workbooks
    For Each wSheet In wBook.Worksheets

        Set rFound = wSheet.Cells.Find(What:=lookfor, After:=wSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then

            firstAddress = rFound.Address

            Do

                Application.Goto rFound, True

                MsgBox "The Search String has been found these locations: "

                Set rFound = wSheet.Cells.FindNext(rFound)

            Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> firstAddress

        End If

    Next wSheet

Next wBook
On Error GoTo 0
```

Anyone has an Idea how to solve this? Thanks!

EDIT: I want it to find both: 98% and 0.98

Comment: You never define the variable that your search value is in. So it will by definition become an integer if I remember correctly.

Comment: yes, you are correct that I don't define it. However, it does not seem to become an integer as I find 0.98.

What would be the appropriate definition? I use the macro for many different types of values..

Comment: I think best would ve to convert the values in the worksheet to either all fractions or all percentages. Otherwise you end up checking against two variables.

Comment: Why `On Error Resume Next`? If you need that for your code to run, you should do something about the errors rather than hide them.

Comment: If both `0.98` and `98%` are stored in Excel as numeric values (usually the case), they will **BOTH** be stored as `0.98` and the only difference will be the formatting.  So you will have to look at that in order to differentiate. In addition, if either value is the result of a calculation, it will likely not be `0.98` exactly, but would be being displayed that way.  So you would have to search for the rounded value, or examine the `.text` property of the range object and not the `value` property.  Hard to tell without your actual data.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Strange as it seems (it surprised me, as I never paid attention to this), if you select a cell with, say, 98% as its contents (formatted as Percentage, and with the value "hardcoded", not resulting from a formula), what you see in the input field is "98%", not "0.98". `find` may be comparing against this.

Comment: @sancho.s Yes, but OP is looking at `Selection.Value`.  That value will be 0.98 whether the cell shows 98% or 0.98.  So `lookfor` will be 0.98.  Range.Find won't find 98% in that situation.  To differentiate, he could search for `Selection.Text`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Even if the numeric value stored is 0.98 (no doubt about it, as it can be used in calculations), there seems to be no way for `Find` to look for those numeric values. It appears that `Find` unavoidably looks for values with a given format. You mention how to differentiate both cases. The OP wants exactly the opposite: not to differentiate them. See my answer below.

Comment: You can't `.Find()` multiple values in the same line of code. You need to use a second loop or some logical operators to look for more than one value

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes 98% is the value of the cell. i.e. when you type out 98% in a cell. Excel will treat it as literally 98%. In other cases the cells value is .98 or .98231 and displays 98%. Most likely you want to look for the roundup to two significant digits so that it finds .98 when the value is .98321.

I would try looking for both.

The cell.text and round(cell.value, 2)

[How to round up with excel VBA round()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017501/how-to-round-up-with-excel-vba-round)

This article shows how to use the round feature in Excel VBA

Comment: thank you, unfortunately the result is not exactly what I am looking for (my question was probably unclear..); 

I want to find both: 0.98 and 98%.. with your solution, the macro only finds 98% if the active cell value is 98%.

Comment: I hope that explains what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, `Find` is missing values with various formats (not only Percentage), even if the numeric value is the same as the source (parameter `What` of function `Find)`.
Under a variety of conditions, listed below, `Find` only finds cells whose contents is `0.98`, either with General or Number (2 decimal digits) format.

What I tried:

1. Using `lookfor = Selection.Value`. Changing the number format of the (source) cell pointed at by `Selection`. It doesn´t matter if the format of `Selection` is Percentage, Number (with any decimal digits), or General. `Find` only finds cells with `0.98`, and not with `0.980`, e.g.
2. Using `lookfor = Selection.Text`. Changing the number format of the (source) cell pointed at by `Selection`. `Find` only finds cells with the exact same number as viewed.

Strange as it may be, this requires a workaround, as `Find` would not find both `0.98` and `98%` at the same time.
One option is to have one or more helper columns with a uniform format, and perform `find` on these columns.

Answer (score 0):

When `FIND` does not work, one solution is to loop through the cells.  If you have a large number of cells, this can be slow, so reading the range to be searched into a variant array will improve the speed by ten-fold or more.

But here is an idea with looping that will get you started.  Note I used the `value2` property.  See [Charles Williams Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2) for the why.

First run the `Setup` macro, then the `findValuePercent`, to see how things work.  You can then adapt it to your specific requirements.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Setup()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
With WS
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "98%"
    .Cells(2, 1).Value = 0.98

    Debug.Print .Cells(1, 1).Value, .Cells(1, 1).Text ' --> 0.98    98%
    Debug.Print .Cells(2, 1).Value, .Cells(2, 1).Text ' --> 0.98    0.98
End With
End Sub

Sub findValuePercent()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim R As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim S As String
    Const dWhat As Double = 0.98

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set R = WS.UsedRange

For Each C In R
    If C.Value2 = dWhat Then
        S = S & vbLf & C.Address & vbTab & C.Text
    End If
Next C

MsgBox "Matches in" & S

End Sub
```